# Event capturing phase is not working as expected on html element which don't have children nodes

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, event-bubbling, event-capturing

Lets consider following html

```
<div id='outer'>
    Outer Tag
    <div id='inner'>Inner Tag</div>
</div>
```

Applying events

```
var outer = document.getElementById('outer'),
    inner = document.getElementById('inner');

outer.addEventListener('click',function(){
   console.log('Outer Clicked!')
}, false);

outer.addEventListener('click',function(){
   console.log('Outer Captured!')
}, true); // event capture flag set to true

inner.addEventListener('click',function(){
   console.log('Inner Clicked!')
}, false);
```

So now, we have applied events and as expected when we clicked on `inner element` the out put should be as follow

> Outer Captured!
>       Inner Clicked!
>       Outer Clicked!

But if we removed `inner span` from above html then it seems like capturing phase is fired after bubbling phase as follow

> Outer Clicked!
>       Outer Captured!

Can anybody explain why this happens?

Comment: Have you tried this in different browsers?

Comment: Also, have you tried clicking the outer element when the inner element is present to see what happens?

Comment: @PetarVasilev yes I also tricked that, its basically happens with single DOM element.

Comment: @PetarVasilev I have tested it on Chrome, Firefox, IE latest versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the target element there is no distinction made between bubbling and capturing - the event is in the [target phase](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-flow). All event handlers registered on it will be fired, and they will be fired in the order they were installed.

Comment: Thank u! @Bergi :)